# Walkie-talkie and its origin

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the word 'Walkie-talkie?' And why that word sounds so childish. For me it is associated with a toy phone for kids or something like that.
Walkie-talkie seems to be a serious thing, but it sounds foolishly.

Answer (score 10):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkie-talkie):

> Canadian inventor Donald Hings was the first to create a portable radio signaling system for his employer CM&S in 1937. He called the system a "packset", although it later became known as a "walkie-talkie". In 2001, Hings was formally decorated for the device's significance to the war effort. Hings' model C-58 "Handy-Talkie" was in military service by 1942, the result of a secret R&D effort that began in 1940.
>
> The first device to be widely nicknamed a "walkie-talkie" was developed by the US military during World War II, the backpacked Motorola SCR-300. It was created by an engineering team in 1940 at the Galvin Manufacturing Company (forerunner of Motorola). The team consisted of Dan Noble, who conceived of the design using frequency modulation; Henryk Magnuski, who was the principal RF engineer; Marion Bond; Lloyd Morris; and Bill Vogel.
>
> The first handheld walkie-talkie was the AM SCR-536 transceiver from 1941, also made by Motorola, named the Handie-Talkie (HT). The terms are often confused today, but the original walkie-talkie referred to the back mounted model, while the handie-talkie was the device which could be held entirely in the hand. Both devices used vacuum tubes and were powered by high voltage dry cell batteries.

What I find interesting about this history is that what we have today keeps the phrase *walkie-talkie*, even though it is hand-held, and it would have been more appropriate for us to have kept *handie-talkie* instead.

Comment: Lots of tech keeps using the name of the original version.  Although "tape" as a synonym for "record" is starting to fall out of use in some contexts.  But a "phone" these days is often more accurately described as a "pocket computer".  Whichever word sounds better or good enough, and is unambiguous, is likely to stick longest, I'd guess.

Comment: "Walkie-talkie" has a better rhyme, and a more pleasant alternation between front and back consonants.

Comment: "handie-talkie instead." but the main selling point is that you can walk with it, not that you can hold it in your hand...

Comment: On that last point, the explanation I heard as a kid in the 90s (when we had landlines and no cell phones) was that the "walkie" part referred to being able to take it with you wherever you went.

Answer (score 7):

According to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/walkie-talkie#etymonline_v_25438), it was coined in the year 1939 during World War II. It is an army slang, from walk (v.) + talk (v.).